# Watch for CD in background

Tags: c#, .net

I have found [this code](http://en.csharp-online.net/Detect_CD-ROM_Insertion) to watch for a CD to be inserted/ejected using C#.  I'm curious if this can be efficiently tuned into a background process/timer function without any significant loss of performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using background processes or timers, I would advise you to use the triggers provided by `ManagementEventWatcher`.

You can find an example implementation here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/295008/How-to-Detect-Insertion-of-a-CD-ROM

Comment: that's the same code.  so, if I understand correctly, then MEW acts similarly to BPs or timers for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: I wouldn't say thay. While they can serve the same purpose, the Event Watcher just listens to some events triggered by Windows, including the one you're interested in. You don't have to actively perform the check, you just get notified when something happens. Your code is completely passive.

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of a windows service that performs an action on CD tray activity. I'm sure that can be done pretty easily and efficiently.

Comment: writing an app that will automatically scan discs when inserted.

Comment: Look at win services, looks that it'll help you with what you are trying to make.

Comment: Should be pretty easy; You'll just need to set up the WMI query shown in your linked post, then find something to do in the meantime to keep the app's main thread from exiting. Blocking the thread is better than looping endlessly, but you can't just use the Console.ReadLine() method of the example.